Google Play app rejection "broken functionality" but the app works fine
I am working on an update to an existing app on the Google Play Store (also on Apple).  The new version installs, loads, and runs fine on 4 different real, physical devices, 4 different emulators at Firebase Test Lab, and the pre-launch report on Google Play.  But, when I submitted the build for "Closed Testing" to get out to my testers, Google rejected the build with the reason "Broken Functionality" and the claims the app does not load and run.  I have appealed the decision, but the response is just the canned text: your app violates the "broken functionality" policy.  Fix the app and resubmit.  They do not provide any details or error messages.  There is nothing I can do to fix the app because it works correctly in every test scenario I have used: both physical devices and emulators.  I have replied to the Google Play review teams email and they only respond with the canned text.
So, is there any way to debug my code in a way to figure out why it's not working properly in their (Google) specific environment?
Any ideas?  any help appreciated.
Physical devices are:  Samsung S9 Android 10,  Pixel 8 Android 14, Pixel 7A Android 14 and Pixel 7 Android 14.   Emulators are a broad range from Motorola, Samsung, and Pixel.
I have run the build on multiple devices, both physical and virtual.  The app runs correctly in EVERY test scenario.
We use AppCheck to secure access to Firebase Firestore, and AppCheck doesn't run in the emulator, but the app still loads and runs with the hard-coded graphics and text, but none of the database content.

Google has notoriously terrible developer support so I doubt you'll get an answer from them - Not sure if this is strictly within TOS but have you tried having your app phone home with logs so you can get some idea of where their issue is remotely?

Also I noticed the newest version you've tested on is Android 14, have you tried testing with Android 15? Could be that's what they're using to test and it breaks on that version only

If you use AppCheck, you can still test in emulator by adding a debug token provided in logcat. But if you're submitting it to Play store, then AppCheck should be able to pass given the app is downloaded from Google Play right? In which case, you typically have to provide a test user which can see real data. Especially if you submit an update after a long time it goes through manual testing to ensure the app still adheres to privacy policy, subsequent updates are usually automated and quicker. Is there any chance you are able to provide them with a test user with actual data?

Hello all, thanks for your comments.  I have tested it on Android 15 and it works correctly.  I don't know what kind of "phone home with logs" I can put in because the app works correctly in all of my test scenarios: now 5 physical devices and 10 different emulators.  For AppCheck I use a debug token for my testing, but I can't include one in the submitted build to Google as that will go into production and I don't want to have a debug token in the production code.  I have supplied them with a test user and password, but apparently the app doesn't even get to the login prompt.  I'm stumped.

@Marsroverr Google is claiming the app doesn't even load, so I'm not sure what kind of log messages I could capture and send home.  What ideas/suggestions do you have?
